# Command not executing in python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from typing import Dict, List, TextIO

def read_grades(gradefile: TextIO) -> Dict[float, List[str]]:
    """Read the grades from gradefile and return a dictionary where each key is a grade and each value is the list of ids of students who earned that grade.

    Precondition: gradefile starts with a header that contains no blank lines, then has a blank line, and then lines containing s dtudent number and a grade.
    """
    # skip over the header

    line = gradefile.readline()
    while line != 'n/':
        line = gradefile.readline()

    # read the grades, accumulating them into a dict
    grade_to_ids = {}

    line = gradefile.readline()

    while line != '':
        student_id = line[:4]
        grade = float(line[4:].strip())

        if grade not in grade_to_ids:
            grade_to_ids[grade] = [student_id]
        else:
            grade_to_ids[grade].append(student_id)

        line = gradefile.readline()

    return grades_to_ids
```

Issue: The python shell says executing command please wait for result but never gives result

Comment: "The python shell says executing command please wait for result" That doesn't look like anything the normal REPL does, are you running this online somehow? How *exactly* are you running this? Note, the code you posted is merely a function definition that never gets called, so I wouldn't expect any output.

Comment: `while line != 'n/':` is an infinite loop - even in the unlikely case that your file has a line consisting of an `n` followed by a slash, it would also have a newline character terminating the line.  You presumably want `'\n'`, and probably also should have a case for `line == ''` to handle reaching the end-of-file without ever seeing a blank line.